# Intellij Can't access classes from one module in other module

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have set up my project as Empty Template and added Spring boot project as a module and another module ecomm-models (This contains purely java classes).

I cannot access classes in ecomm-models inside Spring boot project even though I added it as a dependency in Spring-boot project.

Both these projects are under parent-module as in picture.

Any advise that would be great!

[image]

[image]

After adding models dependcy in Spring boot. Spring-Boot pom.xml looks like this in pic.

[image]

Comment: you'll need to add a dependency from the one module on the other

Comment: I convert the ecomm-models to maven by adding framework. Now I added its dependency in Sprint boot. It still doesn't recognize the classes inside model.

Comment: do you have in your pom.xml a dependency from the one module on the other?

Comment: yes, I can see the ecomm-models dependency in Spring boot pom.xml and I just updated my post with pom.xml

Comment: Surprisingly I can access class/controllers of Spring boot in ecomm-models but the other way around

Comment: did you do a re-build/re-import?

Comment: Yes, but it just doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172677/discussion-between-vyeluri5-and-stultuske).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The missing part in this project is to add packages inside the ecomm-models project/module.

The path should look like

ecomm-models > src > main > java > {package name} > person.java

Since I didn't create a package, it couldn't find the reference.

Answer (score 0):

In an alternative scenario, someone might have committed *.iml file and some .idea config that is outdated. This will confuse IntelliJ when importing, so delete them and open the project again.

Disclaimer:
I can see that there is already an accepted answer that, yet for completeness, I am adding the lines above.